# port scanning an IP range in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, port-scanning

So I'm working on a simple port scanner in python for a class (not allowed to use the python-nmap library), and while I can get it to work when passing a single IP address, I can't get it to work using a range of IPs.

This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from socket import *
from netaddr import *

# port scanner
def port_scan(port, host)
   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
   try:
      s = s.connect((host, port))
      print "Port ", port, " is open"
   except Exception, e:
      pass

# get user input for range in form xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx-xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx and xx-xx
ipStart, ipEnd = raw_input ("Enter IP-IP: ").split("-")
portStart, portEnd = raw_input ("Enter port-port: ").split("-")

# cast port string to int
portStart, portEnd = [int(portStart), int(portEnd)]

# define IP range
iprange = IPRange(ipStart, ipEnd)

# this is where my problem is
for ip in iprange:
   host = ip
   for port in range(startPort, endPort + 1)
      port_scan(port, host)
```

So when I run the code, after adding print statements below

```
host = ip
print host   # added
```

and then again after

```
port_scan(port, host)
print port   # added
```

I end up with the following output:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/python# python what.py
Enter IP-IP: 172.16.250.100-172.16.250.104
Enter port-port: 20-22
172.16.250.100
20
21
22
172.16.250.101
20
21
22
...and so on
```

Thanks in advance everyone! 
I appreciate any help that I can get!

[code picture for reference, slightly different](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDApd.png)

[output picture for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJF6d.png)

Comment: That output by itself doesn't look problematic, unless you know for a fact that some of those ports are open.  It's generally a bad idea to have an `except Exception` in your code, because that will mask a wide variety of errors that might otherwise help diagnose the problem.  Maybe stick a `print` statement in the except block to see what's going on.

Comment: yes I'd be curious to see if the difficulties arise from using netaddr.IPrange, which provides a list of netaddr.ip.IPAddress.  But as stated, it seems as though you are hiding all of your errors.

Comment: Don't forget to close the sockets

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! I followed all of the advice ya'll gave, and the problem turned out to be an issue with using the netaddr.IPRange, as suggested by @bravosierra99. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be an issue with using the netaddr.IPRange, as suggested by @bravosierra99.

Thanks again everyone!